# Mysql Insert date in a database

Tags: php, mysql, dateinterval

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table_timesheet (name, datein, dateout)
VALUES ('Rupert', 'NOW()', '')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE datein='NOW()'
);
```

But this returns an error.

Basically I don't want to insert a record if the 'datein' field of the record already exists in another record - how to check if the new datein is unique?

And how can i insert in the same way the date out on the same row something like an update the datein row?

Comment: insert into .. values doesnt support a where clause.. need to use insert into .. select

Comment: `'NOW()'` is a function, not a string literal; drop the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This INSERT query will do exactly what you want:

```
INSERT INTO table_timesheet (name, datein, dateout)
SELECT 'Rupert', NOW(), null
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table_listnames WHERE datein=NOW()
);
```

Please see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/111b6/1). But a proper solution would be to set a table constraint. How are `table_timesheet` and `table_listnames` related? I would use a unique constraint on the datein column, but this depends on what are your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

first check this query (using MYSQLI or PDO ) if this query return false than you insert record

IF...  this return false

```
SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE datein='NOW()'
```

FALSE

```
INSERT INTO table_timesheet (name, datein, dateout)VALUES ('Rupert', 'NOW()', '')
```